# Why is my complex google sheets function not working and what can be done to fix it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following function that works perfectly:

`=JOIN(", ", TRANSPOSE(FILTER(INDEX(INDIRECT("D4:" & E7 & "4"), 0, IF(INDIRECT("D8:" & E7 & "8")=I14, COLUMN(INDIRECT("D8:" & E7 & "8"))-COLUMN(D8)+1)), INDIRECT("D8:" & E7 & "8")=I14)))`

The problem comes when I change it to match with cell I15, it no longer works with the following error.
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 21.

The match with cell I16 works fine much like how I14 does.
My data is formatted such that I14-I16 is dynamically referencing names. The value in cell D8 is also dynamically referencing the same name as in I15. Cell E8 and Cell I14 have the same such relationship which also goes for Cell I16 and cell X8. Please help.

I have tried messing around with the dynamic referencing assuming that maybe D8 is being left out as a value to reference, but I may just have missed something or approached it wrong. Here is a demo:

https://urldefense.com/v3/__https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b9VMr9sweF1oc8RzC900y3ILcLA19pfsM6Z4Xrl92cs/edit__;!!IxBNepYoNVM!ybR6pe3yvZoRnG_gaAfF6qD3t13q2WO6Qa0acoTD5QA4VEKUsM3kKZDfE-Ap_iQHrKTJmnlg05Ix9CSsfYSXHZWl$

Comment: Hi.. Can you explain super simple way whats the criteria in general to filter these 4 names (from Sheet1) & what are those numbers deduced in the next step? In other words what is it exactly you are trying to extract from your main tab `Sheet1`?

Comment: why do you want to return the row of the person?

Comment: The criteria for filtering the names from that I13 function that occurs in T2:Y2 is subjective based on outside needs and grouping visualization.

Row 4 in sheet 2 represents the row numbers where the complete column is not marked. 
Row 8 Shows whether their is a name in the M/"Assigned to" column of that row.

The idea is to show the rows of incomplete rows for each individual from that I13 formula in the J13:J16 range. Realistically there will be an IFERROR in the final iteration so that J13 and J16 will be empty for easier reading, but the whole idea is basically Task Visualization.

Comment: [I've added two alternate approaches here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b9VMr9sweF1oc8RzC900y3ILcLA19pfsM6Z4Xrl92cs/edit#gid=1003793675) for you to test out and see if its helpful in any way.

Comment: That first formula worked perfectly and gave me insight on better approaches for the future! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*The formula [which worked](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b9VMr9sweF1oc8RzC900y3ILcLA19pfsM6Z4Xrl92cs/edit#gid=1003793675) for OP is as follows:*

```js
=let(assign,choosecols(indirect(D1&"!A2:ZZ"),xmatch("Assigned To",indirect(D1&"!A1:ZZ1"))),
     names,sort(unique(tocol(filter(assign,isna(xmatch(assign,T2:Y2))),1))),
     map(names,lambda(Σ,{Σ,join(", ",ifna(filter(sequence(rows(assign),1,2),assign=Σ,choosecols(indirect(D1&"!A2:ZZ"),xmatch("Complete",indirect(D1&"!A1:ZZ1")))="")))})))
```

[image]